# Colorir palavras do RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Meu objetivo é colorir todas as palavras que estejam dentro de aspas duplas, e as aspas também!

Por exemplo: "Este texto precisa ser colorido".

Comment: Dê uma olhadinha nesse projeto aqui: https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `Regex` para selecionar as string com aspas duplas e posteriormente coloril-as

Ex:

```
private void ColorirRichTextBox()
{

    string[] linhas = richTextBox1.Lines;
    foreach (var item in linhas)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matchs = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(item, @"""[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*""");
        foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matchs)
        {

            string mystring = match.Value;

            if (richTextBox1.Find(mystring) > 0)
            {

                int my1stPosition = richTextBox1.Find(mystring);

                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = my1stPosition;

                richTextBox1.SelectionLength = mystring.Length;


                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;

            }
        }
    }
}
```